How can I analyse Lease expiry dates from on-chain event 'Leased'
I have tried the following code:
with leased as(
    select 
    block_time,
    extrinsic_id,
    cast(json_value(E.data, 'strict $[0]') as int) as chain_id,
    c.name,
    cast(json_value(E.data, 'strict $[1]') as UINT256) as region_end_lease_check
    from coretime.events E
    left join query_3798418 C on C.id=cast(json_value(E.data, 'strict $[0]') as int)
    where section='broker' and method='Leased'
)
select
--block_time,
--extrinsic_id,
chain_id,
name,
date_add('day', cast(region_end_lease_check as int) / 180, date '2020-05-26') as calculated_date
from leased
order by 1, 2

This means I treat the second number in the array as a region, and I convert it to a date by using the formula date = genesis + number/180
Is this correct? If not, why not?
dune query

Looks correct to me. What is the problem?
